# Install android app after google signin via oauth.io

Tags: oauth, google-plus, google-oauth, android

Can I configure oauth.io signin via google so it propose to install android app:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs

Currently it works like this:

```
//Authorize your user to facebook
OAuth.popup('google_plus').done(function(x) {
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't find solution to get it work via oauth.io.
I excluded google_plus from oauth.io and reimplemented it by myself with native api.